# CTAN mirror size

Tags: ctan

What is the current (2017) approximate (+/- 50Gb is adequate precision) size of the CTAN mirror ?

I cannot find this information online, the only way to calculate it myself seems to rsync, but this is exactly what I want to know before committing to it.  Michael Doob' [Mirroring CTAN](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-3/tb72doob.pdf) article from year 2001 is obviously outdated, it states that the mirror takes 5Gb, which is clearly no longer true because TeXLive DVD is there.

**Update:** 32Gb, apparently.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! +/- 50 GB? Probably 5 Gb is correct then.

Comment: The page http://ctan.org/ctan/ says "You will need about 50 Gb of hard disk space" to be a mirror.

Comment: If I remember well, if you run `rsync` with `-n` option it does nothing, but gives you the result with the size.

Comment: I remembered well: if you run `rsync` with `-n` option (`--dry-run`), it doesn't do any file transfers, instead it will just report the actions it would have taken. See here: https://ss64.com/bash/rsync_options.html

Comment: So, given the criterion of +/- 50 Gb, the size of a CTAN mirror is 0b.

Comment: Gb = gigabits or gigabytes? The usual convention is B for bytes and b for bits.

Comment: Did you read [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142705/14500) about [Establishing a new LaTeX repository in the university](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119316/14500)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ulrike already has quoted the official page on CTAN.

In addition I can say that currently 34Gb of the requested 50Gb are effectively used. This leaves some room for growth.